# Chrome - assign hotkey to enter text into current text field

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I want a specific text to be entered into the currently focused field in the web page. This is mainly for templates etc. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> to enter `"if blah then { ... } else { ... }"`. Is this possible ? Or one has to develop a new chrome extension ?

Comment: Which OS do you have?

Answer (score 0):

[AutohotKey](http://autohotkey.com) can do this for you.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

#IfWinActive, - Google Chrome$

!V:: SendRaw "if blah then {...} else {...}"

return
```

Here <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> will enter the text you want to in any text filed of Chrome.

You have to assign shortcut for per template as you want, and its drawback is this that you have to run every script to use it anytime which need the RAM.

Comment: Since Chrome is available for OS X and Linux, besides mobile OSes like iOS and Android, and AHK is Windows-only, wouldn't it be better to know which OS the OP is using first? Of course he might be using Windows after all, but it would be nice if people bothered to provide all relevant details about their operating environment.

Comment: @Karan agree with you. My apologies to not asking about OS.

Comment: No apologies necessary dude, and your answer may very well be just want the OP wants *as long as he's using Windows*. I guess if he doesn't bother to comment or simply accepts your answer, Windows it is! :)

Comment: Oh, and as far as the problem of sending braces goes (if he actually wants to do so), won't using [**SendRaw**](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) instead of **Send** do the trick?

Comment: Ah yes! @Karan I forget about that. I don't use it too much that's why :P